# Invalid ResourceDictionary clr-namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

When I add a ResourceDictionary to a folder its clr-namespace is invalid.

[image: clr-namespace not found]
[image: FIle Explorer Before the Class is added]

Adding a class to the same folder

[[image: Folder Explorer with Dummy Class]

corrects the error

[image: clr-namespace found]

How can I resolve the clr-namespace without having to add a class to the folder?

### Addendum

Note:  Removing the dummy class invalidates the namespace again.

Thans Ali Bigdeli!

There are actually 2 errors:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   IDE1100 Error reading content of source file 'C:\path\TS\ResourceDictionaries\RoundButtons.xaml' -- 'Could not find file 'C:\path\TS\ResourceDictionaries\RoundButtons.xaml'.'. TS-XamlProject  C:\path\TS\ResourceDictionaries\RoundButtons.xaml   1   Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XLS0419 Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'TS.StyleDictionaries' that could not be found.  TS  Style1.xaml 4

Comment: have you tried to  change your namespace after file moving?

Comment: Yes, it invalidates the namespace again.

Comment: What about rebuild and reopen your solution/project?

Comment: @AliBigdeli Yes, but the errors returns.  I added the actual error descriptions to my post.

Comment: If you just have a resourcedictionary in that folder then there's nothing in the styledictionaries namespace. Meaning it doesn't exist. Why would you want to add a xmlns to there? The only use is to reference compiled code. You have no code there.

Comment: @Andy Each ResourceDictionaries in the folder will hold a different set of styles.  Then by adding the Dictionaries to my Application.Resources, I will be able to use the styles anywhere in the Solution,  This video demonstrates How it works: [XAML WPF - Styles Part 3, Resource Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9hElE-vx34).  I followed the video to the letter but I sill get the error.  Note: I've tries both "clr-namespace:TS.StyleDictionaries", and "clr-namespace:StyleDictionaries".

Comment: Just take those xmlns out. Only code has a namespace. You have no code. So there is no ts.styledictionaries namespace. Take the xmlns out. Compile. Then use an object browser to take a look at the exe if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Andy You are right.  I didn't need the namespace.  I didn't think that it solved the problem because was still receiving an error in my App.xaml but the App.xaml error was caused by having a style and a resource dictionary in the App.xaml.  Please post an Answer so that I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an xmlns reference in a resource dictionary for it to work.

Let's start an explanation by considering what an xmlns is doing.

When you add an xmlns that is going to pull some compiled objects into memory so you can use them in your resource dictionary.  It will also alias these. Usually. One of the  default ones does not, but anything you add yourself will therefore need to.

Every resource dictionary has by default some of these added so you can use things like Style. What those default namespaces are referencing is fundamentals of the framework.

Hence

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

Without that top default xmlns, you couldn't put a style or datatemplate in your resource dictionary. These are classes which are defined in the net framework.

The second illustrates aliasing and allows you to use the likes of x:Name and x:Type.

```
<Button x:Name="FooButton"
```

Say you wanted a string as a resource.

This is not in the default namespaces, so you need to add an xmlns to use string. It's a class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netcore-3.1

In .net old this was in mscorlib. In net core it's moved.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
                >
    <sys:String x:Key="Submit">Submit</sys:String>
```

So here, I'm telling it I need to load namespace System from System.Runtime.dll and I want to alias that as sys. In that is the string class which I hence reference in xaml as sys:String.

If I had a usercontrol in the root of wpfapp1 that would be

```
    <local:UserControl1
```

Bearing in mind that a usercontrol has code behind and if you took a look in such a usercontrol code behind, you'd see the namespace wpfapp1.

The xaml in a resource dictionary or window knows nothing about your code. It works with compiled objects.  Which is why if you add a converter and try and reference it immediately in a resource dictionary you will see an error. Because that converter hasn't been compiled yet so when the designer uses reflection on the exe or dll it's in, the converter is not there.

That's covered the background to xmlns, let's take a look at namespaces.

When you add a folder to a project structure, this is just a folder.
When you add some code like a class, there's a template which is used to create that stub you get. Create class1 and you get some usings, a namespace and a stub class. This is all built from a template.

You could edit these actually, these templates are "just" files on disk.

When it does this the stub creation process VS looks at your project and the folder you're creating a class in. If you create class1 in the root of project TS then you get a namespace TS. Drag that into some other folder and it's namespace stays as TS. There is no hard link between folder structure and namespace. Add .Banana to the namespace declaration in that class1 and you'd get a TS.Banana namespace once you compiled.

Within your compiled exe ( which the xaml will reflect to see what's in there ) a namespace only exists because there's some code compiled which has that namespace.
If you have some code with the namespace TS.StyleDictionaries then when it's compiled you will have that namespace in your exe or dll.
If you do not have any code with that namespace then when you compiled you will not have that namespace in there at all.

This is the cause of the different behaviour you're seeing when you add a "dummy" class and remove it.
Add it, you get the namespace.
Remove it, you have no code with that namespace and it's not in the compiled exe/dll.

A resource dictionary, by default, has no code behind. It's all about xaml and if you look in that there's nothing looks like a namespace.  XAML is rather different from code and when you merge a resource dictionary in app.xaml you end up with entries in a sort of dictionary<string, object> which is application.current.resources.  To reference these from your app all you need is the key. These are in memory.
This is significant (partly) because, if you recall, the point of an xmlns is to pull compiled code into memory.
I mention this to highlight how different xaml resources and c# objects are in usage.
This is also more a conceptual explanation and glosses over some details. The actual object in memory might only be instantiated when you first use it. That's way beyond beginner knowledge though.

Hopefully this is clear without completely beating the subject to death.

Comment: Clear enough.  I will have to go over it again.  What really through me off is the video I watched.  He clearly added a new folder and a new ResourceDictionary without having the namespace error.  I deduce from your explanation that he must have declared the namespace somewhere else in his project.

Comment: There's a lot to learn with wpf. Put MVVM up near the top of your list if you intend doing any substantial development.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need have at least one class in mentioned namespace. 
ResourceDictionary can be with codebehind (xaml.cs) file.

[image]

**How to add resourceDictionary with codebehind**
When you add new item to project.. you need to choose Page or UserControl
[image]

Than you need change your xaml.cs file: specify your namespace and className which need inherit from ResourceDictionary (instead of Page or UserControl)

```
using System.Windows;

 namespace TS.StyleDictionaries
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
     /// </summary>
     public partial class Theme : ResourceDictionary
     {
         public Theme()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }
     }
 }
```

After that in xaml you need replace Page to ResourceDictionary, additionally specify x:Class attribute and than you can specify your local namespace xaml.

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="TS.StyleDictionaries.Theme"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TS.StyleDictionaries">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="\Themes\ButtonsStyles.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**P.S.
You need specify namespace only when you need to use clr type from it.**
For use resources from other ResourceDictionary you can use MergedDictionaries or put shared ResourceDictionary inside App.xaml

Comment: [XAML WPF - Styles Part 3, Resource Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9hElE-vx34) demonstrates how you can reference a ResourceDictionary without needing a class.